# Redirection: How did the extra word get in the file?

Tags: bash, redirection

I was testing a script and wanted to create a small file with a bit of text in it so I typed the following and forgot to escape the space in the filename:

```
echo "bob">other name
```

When I did `ls`, it showed the file "other" and when I did `cat other`, it showed the contents as:

```
bob name
```

**How did "name" get in the file?** I believe I saw somewhere that you can put redirection anywhere in a command. In fact, I just tested this:

```
echo >other Some text in a file
```

and "Some text in a file" was the contents of "other".

**What is the purpose of this feature?**

Of course, originally, I should have typed:

```
echo "bob">other\ name
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how bash redirection works.

Writing this:

```
echo "bob">other name
```

is equivalent to this:

```
echo "bob" name >other
```

redirection can appear anywhere on the line, the chevron (`>`) only applies to "other".

This allows people flexibility of how they wish to structure their commands. If it looks more clear doing something like this:

```
>file.txt echo "one" "two" "three"
```

then that is up to the person writing the script or command.